# Stack Configuration remove

Tags: stacking

i have only one cisco 2960 running at location. Switch neither connected in stack nor any cable connected, still in running configuration, it shows switch is in stack and having two two interfaces card, ex. 1/0/1 and 2/0/1. 
What is the reason or how to remove stack configuration?

Comment: please provide configurations..

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#show run | in provision
```

Then from `conf t`:

```
(config)#no switch [stack-member-number] provision [switch-version]
```

By filling in the stack-member-number and switch-version from the show run results.